# Add message ID to inbox items

Tags: feature-request, api-v2, inbox

**Feature request:** The [inbox item object](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/inbox-item) should include a `message_id` field. The ID should identify inbox messages uniquely within StackExchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL in the `link` field is sufficient to uniquely identify an inbox message. Each kind of notification has a different format of URL, and you only get one inbox notification per event.

Comment: What happens when a question is migrated to a new site? Won't the link change in this case?